# Logo and ORCID in Quarto Book

Tags: quarto, orcid

I am using Quarto Book for writing an online Book for my students on scientific writing skills (see [politik-wissenschaft.at](https://www.politik-wissenschaft.at/)).

After updating Quarto from 1.1.x to 1.2.280 I cannot use certain options in the _quarto.yml anymore. These options are the following after "book:"

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  
  orcid: "0000-0003-2625-3631"

  date-modified: "2022-11-18"
  lang: de
  logo: "images/pwa-cover.png"

  favicon: "images/pwa-cover.png"

  link-external-icon: false
  link-external-newwindow: false
```

These are the Error Messages I receive:

```
ERROR: Project _quarto.yml validation failed.

In file _quarto.yml
(line 8, columns 3--8) property name orcid is invalid
7:   author: "Franz Eder"
8:   orcid: "0000-0003-2625-3631"
    ~~~~~~
9:   date: "2022-11-10"
ℹ The error happened in location book:orcid.


In file _quarto.yml
(line 10, columns 3--16) property name date-modified is invalid
 9:   date: "2022-11-10"
10:   date-modified: "2022-11-18"
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11:   doi: "10.25651/4.2022.0001"
ℹ The error happened in location book:date-modified.


In file _quarto.yml
(line 13, columns 3--17) property name abstract-title is invalid
12:   abstract: "Eder, Franz. 2022. *Politikwissenschaftliches Arbeiten: Eine Einführung*. Innsbruck: Institut für Politikwissenschaft, Universität Innsbruck. [https://doi.org/10.25651/4.2022.0001](https://doi.org/10.25651/4.2022.0001)."
13:   abstract-title: "How to cite?"
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
14:   language: de
ℹ The error happened in location book:abstract-title.
ℹ Did you mean abstract-url?


In file _quarto.yml
(line 15, columns 3--7) property name logo is invalid
14:   language: de
15:   logo: "images/pwa-cover.png"
     ~~~~~
16:   downloads: [pdf, epub]
ℹ The error happened in location book:logo.


In file _quarto.yml
(line 21, columns 3--21) property name link-external-icon is invalid
20:   open-graph: true
21:   link-external-icon: false
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
22:   link-external-newwindow: false
ℹ The error happened in location book:link-external-icon.


In file _quarto.yml
(line 22, columns 3--26) property name link-external-newwindow is invalid
21:   link-external-icon: false
22:   link-external-newwindow: false
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
23:   site-url: https://www.politik-wissenschaft.at
ℹ The error happened in location book:link-external-newwindow.
```

Can someone tell me what to do? What are my alternatives? Of course, I could comment the "logo" option, but than the logo is gone on the Website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure the right places for orcid (Author) and the logo (sidebar), i.e.

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: Example Title
  author:
  - name: Franz Eder
    orcid: 0000-0003-2625-3631
  date: today
  
  sidebar: 
    logo: cover.png

  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Maybe one last question: I want to add the "citation" at the beginning of the book (in the index.html file - see Eder, Franz. 2022. Politikwissenschaftliches Arbeiten: Eine Einführung. Innsbruck: Institut für Politikwissenschaft, Universität Innsbruck. https://doi.org/10.25651/4.2022.0001.) I did so by writing it into the "abstract" section. But now the headline for this section is "Zusammenfassung" (i.e., abstract in German). How can I change that to "How to cite?". I tried to do it with "abstract-title" but that does not work.